# Problems with lein compile (Clojure)

Tags: java, import, clojure, require, leiningen

I've been trying to find a solution for 3 hours, nothing helps.
There is a lein project with such **project.clj**:

```
(defproject funcs "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.7.2"]])
```

As well, there is a header of **core.clj**:

```
(ns funcs.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:import (java.sql.Connection)
           (java.sql.DriverManager)
           (java.sql.ResultSet)
           (java.sql.SQLException)
           (java.sql.Statement))
  (:require [clojure.string    :as str]
            [clojure.java.jdbc :as j])) ; JDBC Driver for SQLite
```

After `lein deps` i try to compile **core.clj**, but get:

```
Compiling src/funcs/core.clj
Could not locate funcs/core/clj__init.class or funcs/core/clj.clj on classpath.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate funcs/core/clj__init.class or funcs/core/clj.clj on classpath., compiling:(/tmp/form-init8916675856325046616.clj:1:73)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate funcs/core/clj__init.class or funcs/core/clj.clj on classpath.
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:456)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
    at clojure.core$compile$fn__5682.invoke(core.clj:5903)
    at clojure.core$compile.invokeStatic(core.clj:5903)
    at clojure.core$compile.invoke(core.clj:5895)
    at user$eval20$fn__29.invoke(form-init8916675856325046616.clj:1)
    at user$eval20.invokeStatic(form-init8916675856325046616.clj:1)
    at user$eval20.invoke(form-init8916675856325046616.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    ... 14 more
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

Command `ls -R` output:

```
.:
CHANGELOG.md  LICENSE      README.md  src     test
doc           project.clj  resources  target

./doc:
intro.md

./resources:

./src:
funcs

./src/funcs:
core.clj

./target:
classes  native  stale

./target/classes:
META-INF

./target/classes/META-INF:
maven

./target/classes/META-INF/maven:
funcs

./target/classes/META-INF/maven/funcs:
funcs

./target/classes/META-INF/maven/funcs/funcs:
pom.properties

./target/native:
Linux  Mac  Windows

./target/native/Linux:
amd64  i386

./target/native/Linux/amd64:
libsqlitejdbc.so

./target/native/Linux/i386:
libsqlitejdbc.so

./target/native/Mac:
i386  x86_64

./target/native/Mac/i386:
libsqlitejdbc.jnilib

./target/native/Mac/x86_64:
libsqlitejdbc.jnilib

./target/native/Windows:
amd64  x86

./target/native/Windows/amd64:
sqlitejdbc.dll

./target/native/Windows/x86:
sqlitejdbc.dll

./target/stale:
leiningen.core.classpath.extract-native-dependencies

./test:
funcs

./test/funcs:
core_test.clj
```

So I have no idea where the problem is. Help plz =)

Comment: Please include linux `ls -R .` or equivalent from the project root directory.

Comment: @Thumbnail Done!

Comment: The problem was solved by replacing `[org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.7.2"]` on
`[org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.7.15-M1"]`.

Answer (score 5):

`my-functions.core` should be `funcs.core` in your namespace definition. So rather than:

```
(ns my-functions.core ...)
```

Have:

```
(ns funcs.core ...)
```

The problem is that it seems the name of the namespace and the name of the directory the file is in are at odds. An alternative solution would be to change the directory name from `funcs` to `my-functions`.

Comment: I changed, but the problem remained =(

Comment: When things are going bad always try a `lein clean`